# How can I prove this limit?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

This is the problem I have to solve, I tried many times using the definition, but the result is not the one required.

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $ \Bbb P(X_i=0)=p$ and $ \Bbb P(X_i=1)=1-p$ for all $ i \in \Bbb N $. Show that for $ p \in [0,1) $
>
> **$ \lim_{n\to \infty} {\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \over \sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i } = 1 $ almost surely.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: evaluate numerator and denominator seperately using the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i} = \frac{ 1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{1/n \sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i}  $.
By SLLN $ 1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \xrightarrow{a.s} EX_i = p$ and $ 1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i \xrightarrow{a.s} EX^2_i = p$, using the continuous mapping thoerem for $p \neq 0$ you have that $(1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i)^{-1} \xrightarrow{a.s} 1/p$, hence, 
  $$
\lim_{n \to  \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i} = \lim \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \lim(1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i)^{-1} = p/p = 1 \quad a.s.
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $X_i$s are Bernoulli random variables and we have $X_i = X_i^2$.